# Process terminated with status -1073741510?

Tags: c++

I have the following code that compiles without any errors but does not run. Can someone tell me the problem ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int kenken[4][4];
    kenken[2][2] = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                if(i + j + k == 9){
                    kenken[0][0] = i;
                    kenken[0][1] = j;
                    kenken[0][2] = k;
                }

                if(i * j * k == 6){
                    kenken[1][0] = i;
                    kenken[2][0] = j;
                    kenken[3][0] = k;
                }

                if(abs(i - j)== 3){
                    kenken[1][1] = i;
                    kenken[1][2] = j;
                }

                if(abs(i-j) == 2){
                    kenken[3][1] = i;
                    kenken[3][2] = j;
                }

                if(i/j == 2){
                    kenken[0][3] = i;
                    kenken[1][3] = j;
                }

                if(i * j * k == 12){
                    kenken[2][2] = i;
                    kenken[2][3] = j;
                    kenken[3][3] = k;
                }

                cout << kenken[0][0] << " " << kenken[1][0]
                     << kenken[2][0] << " " << kenken[3][0]
                     << "\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `j==0` you're going to get a division by zero error here:

```
if(i/j == 2){
```

As Ben suggested, a fix would be:

```
if( i == 2*j ) {
```

Comment: and can be fixed by writing `if (i == 2 * j)`

Comment: did not check the code, but `i == 2 * j` is not equivalent of `i / j == 2`: `5 == 2 * 2` is `false`, while `5 / 2 == 2` is `true`.

Comment: @n0rd yes in general that is true of course, but in this case `i` is never 5. If 0<=i<5 and 0<=j<5 the expressions are equivalent for all valid `j`.